# The patent WO2013041665A1 is a copy of public knowledge

Tags: patentability, patent-infringement

In reference to the patent: [WO2013041665A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2013041665A1)

The patent WO2013041665A1 is a copy of the multiplication method: Sustainable Sugarcane Initiative (SSI). No presents innovation, this multiplication system is of public knowledge in Brazil, India and other countries.
There is already a lot of publication on this multiplication system.
So this patent application should not be approved. It copies of public knowledge.

Publications, sugarcane multiplication system using bud chip:

http://agridr.in/expert_system/sugar/ssi.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QsQouBXWNBc

http://www.agsri.com/index.html

Answer (score 1):

In PCT system objections to a WIPO application can be registered using **Third Party Observation** method.

> This system allows third parties to make observations through [ePCT
>   public services](https://pct.wipo.int/LoginForms/pctpublic.jsp) referring to prior art which they believe to be
>   relevant to the question of whether the invention claimed in the
>   international application is novel and/or involves an inventive step. 
>   There is no fee for this service.  For a comprehensive user guide, see
>   [ePCT Third Party Observations](http://www.wipo.int/pct/en/epct/pdf/epct_observations.pdf)

Third party observations may be submitted at any time after the date of publication of the international application and before the expiration of 28 months from the priority date, provided that the application is not withdrawn or considered withdrawn.

**Answer to query:-**

patent application list very general method of propagation but as per inventor use of specific polymer makes it novel as none of the prior art uses the said invented polymer.

since 28 months as past no observation can be made in PCT but in case you are interested you can file observation in countries application has entered (i.e. AU and US).